# System is slow after resuming from hibernate

Tags: 12.10, keyboard, 64-bit, mouse, hibernate

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit and when the system wakes up after an hibernate, the mouse is extremely slow, the keyboard doesn't seem to work and I'm forced to reboot my computer.

Does somebody know a solution / workaround for this?

Comment: Hey, what is the size of your swap area?

Comment: hi, my swap is 4 gb

Comment: it's seems that's hibernate is not he problem as it happens the same thing after a long period of inactivity...ideas guys??

Comment: is your computer get heated during the inactivated time period ?

Comment: Does your system still do this?  If so, what does the 'top' command show for processes or try 'saidar' for a more system wide view of your activity. On Ubuntu, you could also open the 'System Monitor' GUI application to see how the disk, cpu and network are being used. The only other thing I could think of is that your CPU is being put into a lower power mode but that isn't likely.